# Help Configuring Associations in Castle Active Record in case of association table

Tags: many-to-many, castle-activerecord, xunit.net

I have tables like

Users (UserId,Username,Password,CreatedOn,CreatedBy)

Roles (RoleId,RoleName,Description,CreatedOn,CreatedBy)

UserRoleMap(UserRoleMapId,UserId,RoleId,CreatedOn,CreatedBy)

These are my entities:

```
[ActiveRecord(Table="Users")]
public class User:ActiveRecordBase<User>
{
    [PrimaryKey(Generator = PrimaryKeyType.Identity, Column = "RoleId")]
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }

    [Property(Column="Username")]
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }

    [Property(Column = "Password")]
    public virtual string  Password { get; set; }

    [Property(Column="CreatedBy")]
    public virtual string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [Property(Column="CreatedOn")]
    public virtual DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [HasAndBelongsToMany(Table="UserRoleMap",ColumnKey="UserId")]
    public IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }

}
[ActiveRecord(Table = "Roles")]
public class Role : ActiveRecordBase<User>
{
    [PrimaryKey(Generator = PrimaryKeyType.Identity, Column = "RoleId")]
    public virtual int RoleId { get; set; }

    [Property(Column = "RoleName")]
    public virtual string RoleName { get; set; }

    [Property(Column = "Description")]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    [Property(Column = "CreatedBy")]
    public virtual string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [Property(Column = "CreatedOn")]
    public virtual DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [HasAndBelongsToMany(Table = "UserRoleMap", ColumnKey = "RoleId")]
    public IList<User> Users { get; set; }
}

[ActiveRecord(Table="UserRoleMap")]
public class UserRoleMap:ActiveRecordBase<UserRoleMap>
{
    [PrimaryKey(Generator = PrimaryKeyType.Identity, Column = "UserRoleMapId")]
    public virtual int UserRoleMapId { get; set; }

    [BelongsTo(Column="UserId",Table="Users")]
    public virtual User UserId { get; set; }

    [BelongsTo(Column = "RoleId", Table = "Roles")]
    public virtual Role RoleId { get; set; }

}
```

I keep getting this error:
ActiveRecordSample.Tests.FrameworkInitializationTest.CanInitializaFramework : Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.ActiveRecordException : Property UserId references table "Users", which does not have a corresponding [JoinedTable] on the class.

Answer (score 1):

- Wherever the column name matches the property name, you don't need to set Column="..."
- User.UserId is mapped to column "RoleId", it should be "UserId" (or as I said in the above point, just don't define it)
- Make sure to understand the [pros and cons of each PK generator](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/20/nhibernate-poid-generators-revealed.aspx).
- When using HasAndBelongsToMany you don't want a separate relationship class (in your case UserRoleMap).
- IIRC you also need to define the other FK in HasAndBelongsToMany with [ColumnRef](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/relations/hasandbelongs.html).